# Removing users accounts with a zero order value inside wordpress multisite database

Tags: sql, database, wordpress, woocommerce

I am looking for a query to best remove user accounts from a multisite database, the database has over 20 thousand users account and a majority of them have 0 orders against them is it possible to delete customers that have no order against their account so in theory an sql query that selects the user where order amount is zero

Comment: Yes.  And with table structures and relationships between the tables we can probably help with that.   Something like `DELETE FROM USERS U WHERE not exists (SELECT 1 FROM ORDERS O where O.USERID = U.USERID`  using a correlated subquery  But why? Just because they haven't ordered doesn't mean it's not a qualified lead that may order in the future.  consider if they come back the pain they have to go though creating an account again.  That would be a putoff to me using your site.

Comment: the challenge we have is it was migrated users from a magento store into a woocommerce store and any user that was migrated without an order can not reset password so these users need removing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the example query you included in the question, it seems like Order is a column in your table that holds the total number of orders. If so, a delete command like below would work:

```
delete from user
where order = 0
```

If each order is shown by a different entry, you will need the list of UserIDs and use those in your delete command like below:

```
delete from Users
where UserID in (
                  Select F_UserID
                  From Orders
                  Group by F_UserID
                  Having count(*) < 1
                )
```